# Show jQuery modal Dialog from serverside

Tags: .net, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, jquery-ui-dialog

this is the first time i'm using jQuery dialogs so this question might be somewhat simple but i haven't found answers on this yet.

I'm using ASP.Net Ajax to perform an asynchronous postback when user enters something into a Textbox(actually scanning a barcode). This is working like a charm.
Now i need to let the user decide between two options under certain conditions. Therefore i need the postback to decide if this dialog must be shown and what content it has.

**Q:** How to open a jQuery UI (modal) dialog from serverside, let the user choose an option, postback again to server and handle this decision.

I think i need `AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` to register the script that opens the dialog, am i right? If yes, what script opens the dialog onload?

Can i then postback to server by setting `AutoPostback=true` on the control(f.e. RadioButtons or a DropDownList)inside the dialog and handling the appropriate events?

What is the best/easiest way to accomplish what i'm trying?

**Edit**: I considered to encapsulate the dialog into an ASP.Net UserControl and show/hide it. Is this approach recommendable or will it conflict with jQuery in any way?

Your help is greatly appreciated on any of these questions.

---

---

**My Solution**(thanks Kappa):

Also helpful was this link: [Using JQuery UI Dialog with ASP.Net and AJAX Update Panel](http://blog.roonga.com.au/2009/07/using-jquery-ui-dialog-with-aspnet-and.html) and the comment there from Richard.

I have created a UserControl as Container for the jQuery-Dialog:

Dialog-ASCX:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="DialogRecurringRMA.ascx.vb" Inherits="ERP.DialogRecurringRMA" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function createDialog() {
        //setup dialog
        var source = $('#Dialog_RecurringRMA').parent();
        $('#Dialog_RecurringRMA').dialog({
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            autoOpen: true,
            draggable: true,
            width: 420,
            height: 200,
            title: '<%= Title %>',
            open: function (type, data) {
                $(this).parent().appendTo(source);
            }
        });
    }

    function showDialog() {
        $('#Dialog_RecurringRMA').dialog("open");
    }

    function closeDialog() {
        $('#Dialog_RecurringRMA').dialog("close");
    }

    </script>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdDialog" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <div id='Dialog_RecurringRMA' style="display:none">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RblApplyRmaToCharge" ValidationGroup="Dialog" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Create new RMA and add it to current Charge</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">Do not create new RMA</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NothingSelected" Display="None" ControlToValidate="RblApplyRmaToCharge" ValidationGroup="Dialog" runat="server" ErrorMessage="You have to decide whether RMA should be applied to current charge or not">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="NothingSelectedExtender" BehaviorID="NothingSelectedExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="NothingSelected" Width="250px"  PopupPosition="BottomRight"  HighlightCssClass="highlight" WarningIconImageUrl="~/images/warning.gif" CloseImageUrl="~/images/close.gif" />
            <br /><br /><br /><br />
            <asp:Button ID="BtnApply" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:Page_ClientValidate();if(Page_IsValid)closeDialog();" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="Dialog" Text="apply selection" />
    </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Dialog-Codebind:

```
Public Class DialogRecurringRMA
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Public Enum DialogResult As Int32
        NoResult = 0
        CreateRma = 1
        DoNotCreateRma = 2
    End Enum

    Public Event DialogClosed(ByVal dialog As DialogRecurringRMA)

    Public Property Title As String
        Get
            If ViewState("Title") Is Nothing Then
                ViewState("Title") = "RMA with this IMEI found, create anyway?"
            End If
            Return DirectCast(ViewState("Title"), String)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            ViewState("Title") = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property CreateRmaText As String
        Get
            Return Me.RblApplyRmaToCharge.Items(0).Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.RblApplyRmaToCharge.Items(0).Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property DoNotCreateRmaText As String
        Get
            Return Me.RblApplyRmaToCharge.Items(1).Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.RblApplyRmaToCharge.Items(1).Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Result() As DialogResult
        Get
            If Me.RblApplyRmaToCharge.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
                Return If(Me.RblApplyRmaToCharge.SelectedIndex = 0, DialogResult.CreateRma, DialogResult.DoNotCreateRma)
            Else
                Return DialogResult.NoResult
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub Reset()
        Me.RblApplyRmaToCharge.SelectedIndex = -1
    End Sub

    Private Sub CloseDialog()
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, GetType(Page), UniqueID, "closeDialog()", True)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ShowDialog()
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(Page), UniqueID, "createDialog();showDialog()", True)
    End Sub

    Public Sub OpenDialog()
        Reset()
        ShowDialog()
        Me.UpdDialog.Update()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub BtnApply_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles BtnApply.Click
        Page.Validate()
        If Me.Page.IsValid Then
            CloseDialog()
            RaiseEvent DialogClosed(Me)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Its as simple as possible to show the dialog now from where it is used:

```
Me.DialogRecurringRMA1.OpenDialog()
```

In my case it was a little complicated, because the Dialog-ascx was used here:

```
MasterPage -> Page -> TabContainer-Panel -> UserControl -> UserControl -> Dialog
```

But that worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open an already created jQuery UI dialog, you have to call the `$("#elementId").dialog("open");` command.

So, your server side code has to find out if a dialog must be shown, and then it must register a JavaScript to open it using that command.

Edit:

Regarding the `AutoPostback="true"` issue: to ASP.NET it doesn't matter if your commands are inside a jQuery UI dialog or not, the dialog itself is only a `div` with `display: none;`.

**Beware:**

I don't know if you're aware, but when you apply the dialog, the element receiving it gets moved to the end of the `body` element.

It means that it will be **outside** the `form` element, and everything inside will never be posted back to the server (I hit my head on this two days ago).

To overcome this issue you must declare the dialog this way: `$("#elementId").dialog().parent().appendTo("#formId");`, this way the dialog is still moved after the form, but the `.parent().appendTo("#formId")` part moves it back in.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will keep that in mind, but yet don't have experiences on that. I will investigate and report it.

Comment: For others, following link was also very helpful: http://blog.roonga.com.au/2009/07/using-jquery-ui-dialog-with-aspnet-and.html

Answer (score 1):

You probably need some flag in your page (stored in a hidden field or something which is a server control). You can detect this in your $(document).ready() or the link and do whatever. This has to be set on the server side.

But if you are trying to execute a different script on postback (again assuming here its a full postback) use [ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx)

For the second problem I'd have buttons which are server controls on my page which corresponds to the user clicking OK or Cancel (assuming there are the two buttons for the dialog). So I'd have two server side buttons; and also have their respective event-handlers in the code-behind.

Its just that after postback I'd have to hide these two buttons suitable using client side javascript. But I can raise events on it via other javascript code.

Comment: I want to avoid full postbacks whenever possible. Is it a problem for the dialog? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well, there is a technique of making a synchronous XMLHttpRequest based on which can call a server method which does your validation. Based on the response this server method gives you can determine whether to call the jquery dialog or not. BUt this will kinda freeze your whole page I guess. Try the following link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/SynchronousAJAX.aspx